# Debian11 no longer starting into desktop, after (presumed) improper shutdown - causes/fixes?

Tags: virtualbox, debian, desktop, package-management

Every time I restart the VM, Debian11 (guest OS) boots into console. I can login fine. If I then do startx, it does open one little GUI-looking terminal on a screen-filling black background, no normal Debian desktop. (the proper Desktop used to start automatically anway)

It started to do this, after months of working with the Desktop, then after the last shutdown, which might have been improper (e.g. enforced by Windows host rebooting).

What could be wrong and how to diagnose this?

N.B. All I find searching online is people asking Debian getting stuck somehow before the Desktop environment starts. That's not the case here.

Edit:
In the initial list of things the system does when booting, with usually a green [ Ok ], the last entry I see is a red [ FAILED ], saying something about not being able to start a webserver & proxyserver, the message seems to be from NGINX. I see no other error mentioned there, and later, in the console greeting me as tty1,  that it boots into (instead of the graphical desktop), dmesg does not list that error. The only "error"/"fail" I find in the dmesg output is "failed to send host log message", IIRC I saw that before with no apparent bad consequences, and it merrily continues after that.

Answer (score 0):

On occasion, I find Debian and derivative OS can corrupt its *ext4* partition.

However, I also find the *ext4* journaling allows the file system to be easily repaired.

- For me, the easiest way is with a GUI utility, [Disks](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/manage-ubuntu-hdd-disk-utility/).

  - Create a live Linux USB. [Ubuntu Live](https://itsfoss.com/create-live-usb-of-ubuntu-in-windows/) comes with *Disks* preinstalled.
  - Boot from USB, leaving the internal drive *unmounted*.
  - Press the <kbd>System</kbd> key (looks like a window in perspective), type "disk", and select the *Disks* utility.
  - Click on the OS partition, click the *gear* icon, and select, *Repair Filesystem*. **N.B.** Often, this needs to be done *twice*: the first run indicates failure, the second finishes without error. [Sorry, I have no explanation for that.] You can also check and repair, if necessary, other partitions.
  - Close *Disks*, shut down Ubuntu *gracefully*, remove the USB and *hopefully*, the system should now boot from the main drive.
- The alternative, for hardcore Linux users, is to use [fsck](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/fsck-command-linux), for file system consistency check.

  - As above, make a live Linux USB. Neither *fsck* nor *disks* can repair a mounted partition, i.e., the main OS partition.
  - Open *Terminal*. In Ubuntu, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> to do so.
  - Enter `df -h` to identify the OS disk.
  - Assuming the OS is on disk */dev/sda*, enter `sudo parted /dev/sda 'print' to identify the OS partition.
  - Enter `sudo fsck /dev/sda1` to repair that partition, assuming that is the one with OS.

    **N.B.** This is a *greatly* simplified summary of *fsck* usage. See [Tecmint](https://www.tecmint.com/fsck-repair-file-system-errors-in-linux/), for example for details.

Comment: "Enter `sudo fsck /dev/sda` to repair that partition." – If a partition, then `/dev/sda1` or so.

Comment: There seems to be no problem with the file system, running Kubuntu (of which I had a live ISO laying around) equivalent of what's given in the reply, which also runs fsck, showed no errors, reported success, and the behavior is still exactly as described in my OP.